# How can i reduce memory usage in my ios app?

Tags: ios, caching, memory, uicollectionview

I am building a Pinterest like app, which has a uicollectionview with endless cells, each having an image.

Now continually scrolling through the collectionview, more images are loaded and cached.

I am observing that the memory usage is reaching 200MB and increasing.

My question is what are the best practices used in this case ?

Comment: What are you using to cache the images?

Comment: i'm using Kingfisher to load the images, which also caches them... https://github.com/onevcat/Kingfisher

Answer (score 0):

One important thing is to reuse your cell. You can reference to the following method.

```
func dequeueReusableCell(withReuseIdentifier identifier: String, 
                     for indexPath: IndexPath) -> UICollectionViewCell
```

https://developer.apple.com/documentation/uikit/uicollectionview/1618063-dequeuereusablecell

> Call this method from your data source object when asked to provide a
>   new cell for the collection view. This method dequeues an existing
>   cell if one is available or creates a new one based on the class or
>   nib file you previously registered.